# Can phpmyadmin use pdo_mysql to access mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My php installed with `pdo_mysql`, without `mysqli`/`mysql`. When I use phpMyAdmin, it showed

```
"The mysqli|mysql extension is missing".
```

I tried many times to install `mysqli`/`mysql` but failed, and I don't want to re-compile php. So I gave up and chose another mysql web tool Adminer which can use pdo_mysql.

**Question**  : Is it possible that `phpMyAdmin` use `pdo_mysql` to access mysql db?  I think it should be not hard ,since another tool can.

Comment: Your question isn't really about programming. Of course one could write a plugin for PhpMyAdmin to support PDO. Which however would be too broad of a question.

Answer (score 1):

This information is [not immediately available](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/require.html) in the online documentation, but [the FAQ has it](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#which-mysql-versions-does-phpmyadmin-support):

> phpMyAdmin can connect to your MySQL server using PHP’s classic MySQL extension as well as the improved MySQL extension (MySQLi)

The phrasing is [more explicit in their Wiki](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Requirements):

> [Requirements]
>
> (...)
>
> - Either the mysql or mysqli extensions
>
> (...)

So the answer is: not by default, but [contributions are welcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937084/can-phpmyadmin-use-pdo-mysql-to-access-mysql/27939732#comment44271276_27937084) :)